# In Excel how to combine other cell data with a value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

On an Excel worksheet I have two columns ("A" and "B" in the example below) and a specific cell I am referencing ("B2"). Column "B" just has some text. In column "A" I want a formula to combine text from the reference cell "B2" with a value that goes in the order `_01`, `_02`, `_03`, etc., depending on when the adjacent cell in column B is not blank.

Data is formatted like below:

[image]

I have tried the following formula:

```
=IF(B11<>"",B2 & "_" & COUNTA(B11:B101),"")
```

But it's counting in the wrong direction. It's going 3, 2, 1 down and should be counting up. Also it doesn't count for new rows that are added.

Comment: What part of the above are you trying to manually populate? Could you retake the screen shot and add the columns and row numbers as well. It would makes things easier

Comment: Iv actually gotten an answer thanks for the help =IF(B15<>"",$B$2&"_"&COUNTA($B$10:B15),"") .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has found an answer and the post is unlikely to help others

Comment: @AaronRice Please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @Dave I disagree that we should close questions that are otherwise on-topic based on the the OP finding the answer and the subjective assessment of how many others will find it useful.

Comment: Then copy it as the answer with community wiki